# Cluster Analysis for Ratio & Numerator-Denominator Data

Tags: clustering, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

My data is as shown below where ROE is being defined as ***(Revenue - Expenses)/Capital***

**Revenue | Expenses | Capital | ROE**

I'm trying to do a cluster analysis (hclust in R) hoping to get some benchmarks for clusters like ***High Rev & High ROE***, ***Low Capital & High ROE*** etc. But since the variables are so correlated (which I think is the reason), the output is showing 99% of the data in one clusters and the remaining outliers in the others. Is there any transformation or change in the cluster analysis I can apply for much more meaningful insights into such data.